# How to custom the theme of my website depends on user

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, zend-framework2, customization

I'm using bootstrap 3 and i have to set multiple themes ont my website depends on each client we have.

- Client 1 : green theme;
- Client 2 : purple theme;
- Client 3 : grey theme..

And goes on...

**Context**
The solution has to be dynamic, the website looks like the same, juste color change.
For now i use the theme on url (get theme... i search for a better solution)
I can't make a specific css by client type, duplicated code -> maintain impossible.

**My solution for now**

I make a file in php called bootstrap-override.css.php

Wich contain on top this code :

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");

$defaultWhite = $white = '#FFFFFF';
$defaultGray1 = $gray1 = '#E7E7E7';
$defaultGray2 = $gray2 = '#CDCDCD';
$defaultGray3 = $gray3 = '#F2F2F2';
$defaultGrayBlue1 = $grayBlue1 = '#99AEBD';
$defaultGrayBlue2 = $grayBlue2 = '#495D6C';
$defaultBlue1 = $blue1 = '#0094D7';
$defaultBlue2 = $blue2 = '#004F9F';

if (isset($_GET['theme'])) {
    switch ($_GET['theme']) {
        case 'CA':
            $grayBlue1 = '#008168';
            $blue1 = '#009AA5';
            $blue2 = '#2A3B48';
            break;
        case 'CE':
            $defaultGrayBlue1 = $grayBlue1 = '#ABABAB';
            $defaultGrayBlue2 = '#727274';
            $blue1 = '#D70119';
            $blue2 = '#D70119';
            break;
// More client...
    }
}
?>
```

And my css using those variables, I call it using this code :

```
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/websiteName/css/bootstrap-override.css.php'.((!empty($_GET['theme'])) ? "?theme={$_GET['theme']}" : ''))
```

(ZF2 application)

But the switch case part is ugly and the get part too.., i can't leave this in that way if i have a new client type i will make this code more complexe... i wanted a more efficient way to do this.

If someone can help to improve this.

**Edit** : From comments, Store all theme in Database, with a 1/n relationship between client / theme is possible, I had already thought month ago... but my problem for this solution is to design it. If i store this in Database, i have to create a model layer to respect Zend\MVC best practises, and how i design my CSS in this architecture ?

Comment: A more efficient way would be to store the colours for the various themes in your database and generate your strings dynamically from there.

Comment: I had already thought about it, your right. But i don't know how to do this completely, let's say i have my database, with a table and all colors for a client type. How i create the CSS with it in a zf2 application (using MVC)... it's not easy for me, because database interaction are in a model layer, not view...

Comment: but you can send variables to default layout using $this->layout()->color= 'blue';. You can access this variable at default layout using $color or $this->color(if i remember correctly). This way you could use the onBootsrap method inside your Module.php connect to database get and pass the variables to the layout and use them for the css

Comment: Hum, i'm not sure if i understand your point of view @dixromos98. Maybe you can explain this by a developped answer so i can see your point. For me it is not the role of this file (Module.php) to accomplish this task, maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: The reason i am not giving you a developed answer is because i do not understand exactly the problem you have. If the information "CA" and "CE" are in the database then you can create a table and link it to the particular client with type "CA" or "CE". And in that table you could have a complete name of the CSS but that would mean many CSS files or you can have the color codes in different fields you need and then override the CSS according to the values you got from the database.

Comment: Why dont you go the easy way and save  the user choice in $_SESSION?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly I would suggest adding CSS *files* to the HeadLink.

You could have a 'default' CSS file which implements the shared styles for all clients and then a separate, theme specific, CSS file which then specifies the just the styling for `CA`, `CE` etc.

To apply this to the HeadLink view helper you can use an event listener, listening 'on render'.

For example

```
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, [$this, 'addClientCss'], 100);
    }

    public function addClientCss(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $config = $serviceManager->get('config');

        if (! isset($config['custom_css']) || ! is_array($config['custom_css'])) {
            return;
        }

        $viewPluginManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewPluginManager');

        $headLink = $viewPluginManager->get('headlink');
        $basePath = $viewPluginManager->get('basepath')();

        foreach($config['custom_css'] as $cssFilePath) {

            $headLink->appendStylesheet($basePath . $cssFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the configuration in the required `module.config.php`.

```
return [
    'client_css' => [
       '/some/css/path/to/styles.css',
       '/another/path/to/css/file.css'.
    ],
];
```

This would ideally be located in a module that is specific for the client or project you are working on (and also last in the module list in `application.config.php`) so that this config is merged last.

Comment: Well, it's good, but in this case if i understand your answer correctly, i have a file.css for each my client. If i make a modification wich involve to update those file, i lose hours. My solution to handle via PHP some variable (colors) can't be working with your solution, right ? you get color from config here or Database ?